# Trouble with installing vue using npm

Tags: macos, vue.js, npm-install

I was trying to install Vue using the command

`npm install vue`

but the terminal showed ERR like below

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "_@nuxt_opencollective@0.3.0@@nuxt": name cannot start with an underscore; name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

and I don't know why

My system is MacOS 10.15

Comment: Have you updated npm packages? Try running: "npm update" and see what happens

Comment: What version of `node` and `npm`?